# What types of applications have you seen or made with node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm not looking for a definition of what it is, but I'm interested in knowing what types of applications people are ( or plan to ) use it for.

Answer (score 2):

I think that one of the most common use cases is Comet (ajax long polling) applications. Node.JS is very good fit for those, because of its evented nature.

With comet technique you can create real time applications. Like chats etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ry/node/wiki lists different projects/apps using node.js.

Comment: Here's another real world example http://github.com/blog/678-meet-nodeload-the-new-download-server

Answer (score 0):

I've used an IRC bot on the Freenode network that was made with node.js, [Protobot](http://github.com/gf3/protobot).

Answer (score 0):

The latest one making the rounds is: http://projects.nuttnet.net/hummingbird/